# Elastic net regression in orange

Tags: linear-regression, orange

The penalty term for Elastic Net Regression is written as:

$$\lambda_1  \|\theta\|_1 + \lambda_2\|\theta\|_2^2$$

How are the values of lambda's calculated if the slider is moved from the right to the left?

I have read most of the material available on the internet on Elastic Net Regression. Here, they define $\alpha=\lambda_2/(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$. If the value of $\lambda_2 $ and $\alpha$ is given, then $\lambda_1$ is calculated. In Orange the slider is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer. In elastic net the cost function is written as
$J(\theta)=MSE + r\alpha\sum_{i=1}^n \vert\theta_i \vert + \frac {1-r}{2}\alpha\sum_{1=1}^n \theta_i ^2 $. Here $r$ is the ratio, $\alpha$ is the hyperparameter and $n$ is the number of features. The ratio slider controls $r$ and $\alpha$ slider controls the value of hyperparameter.
If the ratio $r=0$, then Elastic net regression is equal to ridge regression. For $r=1$, the Elastic Net Regression is equal to Lasso regression. I hope this perfectly answers the question I posed. I would like to have comments from followers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

If the slider goes from 0 to 1, one possibility:

$$\lambda_1 = 1 - \lambda_2$$

Comment: This means that the value of lambda is between zero and 1. I'm not quite sure of this. I would like to have more clarifications on this.

Comment: The slider on [this screenshot](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/model/linearregression.html) shows as `0.50 : 0.50`, `50:50`, half-half, $.5$. [Orange uses scikit-learn](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/8d9988d7ced95454dee34235c1ede142c8de9bff/Orange/regression/linear.py#L60-L63) underneath, and in [sklearn's ElasticNet implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html#sklearn-linear-model-elasticnet), `l1_ratio` is a parameter on $[0, 1]$.